# 404 error in Spring web app deployed to weblogic 10.3.3.0

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I made a web app with a RESTful web service and some webpages which make ajax calls. I used Java class based configuration instead of XMLs. The war file works well in Tomcat7. Now I am trying to deploy it on Weblogic 10.3.3.0. However, I got this.

1. Going to the root url (http://myaddress.com:7001/myapp/) from browser gives me a error 403.
2. Doing a POST to the web service gives me error 404.
3. I CAN get to the static webpage. (the ajax call would fail due to web service not working)
4. I cannot see any errors in the server log.
5. I tried deploying Spring's example REST project (http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) to the Weblogic server, I got the same issue.

After googling around, I found quite a number of similar questions, but none of them seems to be solved by looking at the thread. Is there any extra configuration I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Now I figure out why it is not working and will answer my own question.

As I mentioned, I used java class based configuration for my web application instead of having a web.xml file inside the WEB-INF folder. Class based configuration is only supported by Servlet 3+ API. However, Weblogic 10.3.3.0 only has support for servlet 2.5. So the application wouldn't work.

Now I have changed the application to use XML based configuration. It is working well in Weblogic 10.3.3.0 now.